# List duplicate with = vs [:] in 3.11.4 vs 3.10

Tags: python, list, copy

When I am using VS Code or IDLE shell with Python 3.11.4 installed I can use either of the following to create a duplicate of a list so that alterations to the new list do not affect the original.

```
new = original[:]
#or
new = original
```

But when using the website CodeSignal, which uses Python 3.11.4 I can only use the first one to achieve that.

Has Python changed the behavior of lists in newer versions or is there another cause for this?

I am new to Python and coding in general so I apologize if this is a silly question.

Comment: `=` does not make a copy. Ever. Under any circumstances. It simply creates a new reference to an *existing* object. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: if you want to preserve original list then you have to use `list[:]` or `list.copy()`. For nested lists it many need `copy.deepcopy(list)`

Comment: @chepner - except on item assignment. `foo[0] = bar` could have a `__setitem__` that copies. Unexpected, but possible.

Comment: @tdelany Yes, I should have said assignment to a *name*. (Something like "`=` with a name does not ...")